# initializing variable with select in init method using x++

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm new with X++ and I'm trying to modify the INIT method of a form in order to greet the user wit a message on top of the form.
 The greeting message should look like "Happy Birthday *EmplTable.name*!".
 The code from the INIT METHOD looks like this till now:

```
public void init()
{
    CustName    custName = SELECT EmplTable.name FROM Empltabe JOIN   UserLogInfo WHERE EmplTable.EmplId == UserInfo.UserId;

    ;

    //"@NET4183"
    super();
    GreetingMessage.text(strfmt("@NET4183", custName));
}
```

I have a hard time understanding what is wrong here and why I can't initialize the custName variable.
 Thank for the help!
 Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables must be declared before they can be used. X++ does not allow variable declarations to be mixed with other X++ statements; variables must be declared before X++ statements.

[Declaration of Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa598112.aspx)

You should declare variables EmplTable, UserInfo before you can use them in select statement.

Results of a `select` statement are returned in a table buffer variable. If you use a field list in the select statement, only those fields are available in the table variable. 
You can assign value to your `custName` variable using this peace of code

```
custName = emplTable.name;
```

This link will give you a hint how to find the current user

[curUserId Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa630899.aspx)